# Remember to push feature branch before submitting a pull request?

Tags: git, github

I apologize if this has been asked before - I am unable to find a definitive existing answer on SO.  I have just started using the process described [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (A Successful Git Branching Model).  I am having my team members submit pull requests on GitHub when they're ready to merge their feature branches into the develop branch.  However, a developer always has to remember to perform a

```
$ git push origin branch-XYZ
```

before submitting the pull request, right?  If you've built everything locally, then forgotten to push that feature branch to origin, it seems like it could lead to a lot of confusion: I merge the feature branch into the develop branch, delete the feature branch on origin, and close the pull request.  But there were 2 commits still sitting in a local feature branch that were never pushed and are effectively gone forever.  Anyone know of a better way to handle this other than "just remember to push"?  Am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> before submitting the pull request, right?
> If you've built everything locally, then forgotten to push that feature branch to origin

Its pretty simple:
If you want the code on the server simply push it.

If you want you can set your `post-commit` hook and add an echo line to remind you to push to the server

> ***`post-commit`***
> After the entire commit process is completed, the post-commit hook runs

---

#### Sample hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Output colors
red='\033[0;31m';
default='\033[0;m';

echo "${red}"
echo "                                         "
echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
echo "                                         "
echo "                                         "
echo "  Push, Push Push the code to remote     "
echo "                                         "
echo "${default}"

exit 0;
```

Comment: A post-commit hook sounds like a good idea.  Nice picture by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

"Just remember to push" is pretty much it. But one avenue you may wish to explore is to write a shell script does the following:

- Executes `git push`.
- Obtains the name of the current branch, by either running `git status`, or any other way.
- Uses the Github API to submit a pull request.

And then require a policy to always use the shell script to submit pull requests, rather than manually.

Comment: GitHub's own [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) tool will take care of the second two items.  After installing it, you can simply run `git pull-request` to open a pull request on github.